# Is "you look like your dad" a simile?

Tags: simile

Is "you look like your dad", or indeed any statement of looking like something in which the description is meant literally (unlike e.g. you look like hell), a simile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you look well at the definition of the simile, the answer to your question becomes evident. A simile is

> a figure of speech comparing **two *unlike* things** that is often introduced by *like* or *as* (as in ***cheeks like roses***) ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simile))

Certainly, cheeks are not roses, it is their colour that is the feature they have in common with those particular flowers. Things are different in your example. The fact that two persons look alike, is a physical description between two beings or entities that are not ***unlike*** but ***alike***. Therefore, it is not a simile.

Comment: well I agree, and agree you have shown it, but I don't think it's quite "evident"

Comment: but yeah I think the word 'literal' is useful there. my cheeks don't literally look like roses, because it's a figure of speech. I literally do look like my dad! even though we are not identical, our likeness is not **rhetorical**

Comment: ['Literally'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literally) can be used for emphasis and metaphorically, be ware! _My heart was literally bursting with joy_ does not mean that my heart is in pieces :)

Comment: Yes - and by the same token, *The handwriting on this ransom note is so bad I can't be sure what it says. But **it looks like** they want £1000 for the safe return of my cat* isn't a simile either. Come to that, nor is ***[It] looks like rain tomorrow***.